# What does this line mean? Bold space?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This one:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

I've came upon this strange line, and I wonder what it does. From what I understand, it outputs a "space" character, and the `<strong>` tag (see below) wants to make it bold, but that sounds useless. Is there something I don't understand?

Here is the code snippet:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="prix = '0' ">
        <strong>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </strong>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="prix" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

> From what I understand, it outputs a "space" character

No, it doesn't. It outputs an empty string, i.e. nothing. In your example, when the test `"prix = '0'` returns true, the result tree will contain:

```
<strong/>
```

i.e. an empty `strong` element.

> is "value-of" the only way to output content in a template?

No, of course not: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-the-Result-Tree

> Can the "xsl:text" tag be used for this as well

The `xsl:text` element can output literal text only.

> There is no end tag in my example.

It does not need an end tag, since it is empty and "self-closing". This form:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ></xsl:text>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Can't see any reason for it.**

I suspect it might have been put in there by a previous developer because at one point they had some useful information in that element, but eventually didn't need it and figured just closing the tag would be the quickest (although not the cleanest) way of dealing with it.

Comment: That was my guess as well. I was suspicious the first time I saw this, but then I saw it 3 more times in the same file and I was confused. But thanks, I guess it confirms my thoughts.

Comment: XSL is a template language.  Could the actual content be coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well indeed, but I thought the only way to output content in the template was to use "value-of", as seen in the snippet.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, in fact that was a question. Let me rephrase: is "value-of" the only way to output content in a template? Can the "xsl:text" tag be used for this as well, or is it only like a "string" type in C#/Java/etc ?

Comment: That was my question as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

It comes handy if you need to output special characters like ampersand:

```
<div class="clear">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
</div>
```

Explanation from W3Schools:

> Optional. "yes" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be
>   output as is. "no" indicates that special characters (like "<") should
>   be output as "<". Default is "no"

Comment: It does not answer my question. I know what "disable-output-escaping" means. My problem is the fact that my line seems to output absolutely nothing, a space at best. There is no end tag in my example.

Comment: if you have no  content in it, you can remove or comment it out. It has no other purpose there. You should rewrite your **choose** statement then.